# Postdoctoral and Research associate

Tags: postdocs, job

Is there any difference between Postdoctoral fellow and research associate?

Comment: Which country is this about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will vary by institution.

**Post-doctoral fellow**, at least in the US, is almost always a temporary position to bridge between grad school and a faculty position. Some funding agencies (and therefore some universities) require that post-docs received their PhDs within the past 7 years.

**Research associate** can mean almost anything. At MIT, senior research associates:

> "possess a demonstrated research competence equal to that of a tenured faculty member...Appointments are of indefinite duration and are to be reviewed within every five-year period"

So, a potentially permanent, but untenured research position with qualifications parallel to the tenure track. In other contexts, this can be a temporary position granted at any level.